# Get error message of page validators for particular group by javascript in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am trying to write javascript function in which I want to show the error message of the of the invalid fields of the validatiors whose groupname is given.

Basically I am having some different group of validators and want to show there error message in alert if value entered is in valid for the group whose button is pressed using common function.

I am using following code:

```
function check(group) {

        if (Page_ClientValidate(group)) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            var message="";
            for (i = 0; i < Page_Validators.length; i++) {

                if (!Page_Validators[i].isValid) {
                    message = message + Page_Validators[i].Errormessage+ "\n";
                }
            }
            alert("Enter following fields marked with * or Invalid Data\n"+message);
            return false;
        }
```

I want to run following section of code for particular group of validators:

```
var message="";
                for (i = 0; i < Page_Validators.length; i++) {

                    if (!Page_Validators[i].isValid) {
                        message = message + Page_Validators[i].Errormessage+ "\n";
                    }
                }
                alert("Enter following fields marked with * or Invalid Data\n"+message);
                return false;
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood correctly, a simple `switch` statement would do the trick

```
for (i = 0; i < Page_Validators.length; i++) {
    switch(Page_Validators[i].validationGroup)
    {
        case "MyGroup1":
            // your javascript code
            break;
        case "MyGroup2":
            // your javascript code
            break;
        default:
            // your javascript code
            break;
    }
}
```

If you need to see the javascript object properties, set a breakpoint in the javascript and debug using Visual Studio

Comment: No my concern is, in second snippet of my code I ant to run for loop to check validators of particular group only. But hen I run it It checks for validators of complete page.

Comment: Check my updated answer, basically you can use this: `Page_Validators[i].validationGroup` to get the valdiation group and then use an `if` or a `switch` to do something

Comment: Also can you tell me how can we get error message of that validator? Is it something like Page_Validator[i].errorMssage

Comment: It has to be inside the `for (i = 0; i < Page_Validators.length; i++)`

Comment: Hey your code works  I had just made mistake from my side. Thanks a lot.